# scroll on mouse movement

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I have a `div` in my html and i have added `overflow: scroll`. I want it to scroll according to mouse movement. If the mouse is on left side of screen the scroll should be at the start. If the mouse  is on the center of the screen the scroll should be in the center and same goes for right.
[Have a look at this website](https://gallery.tm/dubai/1306-marina-residences-5/). You should see a top navigation bar of thumbnails which scrolls according to your mouse movements. I want the same effect exactly same. I have built it but it's not working as expected. If my mouse is in the center of screen the scrollbar is not the center but at the right side. [have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAKlP.png). Below is my code:

```js
const gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
const activeImage = document.getElementById('active-image');
const thumbnail = document.querySelector('.thumbnail');
const thumbnailWrapper = document.getElementById('thumbnail-wrapper');

thumbnailWrapper.addEventListener('mouseenter', handleMouseMove);
thumbnailWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  const noOfPics = Array.from(thumbnailWrapper.childNodes).length
  const clientX = e.clientX;
  const clientY = e.clientY;
  const width = window.innerWidth;
  const height = window.innerHeight;
  const wrapperWidth = thumbnail.clientWidth * noOfPics;
  const wrapperHeight = thumbnailWrapper.clientHeight;
  const percentX = clientX / width * 100;
  const percentY = clientY / height * 100;
  const scrollX = (wrapperWidth - width) * percentX / 100 - width / 2;
  thumbnailWrapper.scroll(scrollX, 0)
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}

#gallery {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #303030;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#thumbnail-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
}

#thumbnail-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /* display: none; */
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red;
}

.thumbnail {
  flex: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #303030;
  background-color: #202020;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#active-image {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow-scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.fit {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.original {
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="thumbnail-wrapper">
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="active-image" class="overflow-scroll">
    <img src="https://www.lifewire.com/thmb/_cH2YBd-iyPP1cqqj2WWXiCWudg=/1500x0/filters:no_upscale():max_bytes(150000):strip_icc()/hdwallpapersnet-free-wallpaper-5919d3ca3df78cf5fa49bda3.jpg" alt="something went wrong" class="original">
  </div>
</div>
```

It think i am not calculation scrollX correctly i have tried many combination but can't get the behaviour i expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically it's a linear thing, starting from (0, 0) to the (clientWidth, maxScroll). So I calculate the linear formula then it's easy to put in a clientX and get an offsetX.

It might need some tweaking across the edges. Probably calculate the equation from 0+imageWidth to maxWidth-imageWidth.
Have a play with it.

Update: I had a play with it. Now should be perfect.

```js
function getLinearFunction(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
  var slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1);
  return function(x) {
    return slope * (x - x1) + y1;
  }
}


const gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
const thumbnail = document.querySelector('.thumbnail');
const thumbnailWrapper = document.getElementById('thumbnail-wrapper');

thumbnailWrapper.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
// document.addEventListener('key')

function handleMouseMove(e) {
  const noOfPics = Array.from(thumbnailWrapper.childNodes).length
  const clientX = e.clientX;
  const clientY = e.clientY;
  const width = thumbnailWrapper.clientWidth;
  const height = thumbnailWrapper.clientHeight;
  const wrapperWidth = thumbnail.clientWidth * noOfPics;
  const wrapperHeight = thumbnailWrapper.clientHeight;
  const percentX = clientX / width * 100;
  const percentY = clientY / height * 100;
  const scrollLeft = thumbnailWrapper.scrollLeft
  var maxScrollLeft = thumbnailWrapper.scrollWidth - thumbnailWrapper.clientWidth;
  // when clientX = 0 you want scrollx = 0
  // when clientx = width you want scrollX = maxScrollLeft
  var foo = getLinearFunction(0, 0, width, maxScrollLeft);

  // EDIT: improvement: 
  var foo = getLinearFunction(0 + 150, 0, width - 150, maxScrollLeft);

  output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify({
    clientX,
    clientY,
    width,
    height,
    wrapperWidth,
    wrapperHeight,
    scrollLeft,
    maxScrollLeft
  }, null, 4)

  thumbnailWrapper.scroll(foo(clientX), 0)
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}

#gallery {
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #303030;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#thumbnail-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  background: yellow;
}

#thumbnail-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
  /* display: none; */
  background-color: #000;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red;
}

.thumbnail {
  flex: none;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #303030;
  background-color: #202020;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#active-image {
  flex: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.overflow-scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
}

.fit {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.original {
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="thumbnail-wrapper">
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
    <div class="thumbnail"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Yeah it's perfect. Although i still can't get my head around it but will understand it after i complete the project. Already late to deliver this :)

Comment: If you don't mind can you take a second to explain me how it's work. I am sorry i am a junior developer it's my frst month on my first job as a developer

Comment: see there's no reason to believe that the motion of the scrollbar is non linear. what i mean is that it scrolls straight same speed not faster at one point or other. linear. so if at one point (mouse x) you know the value it should scroll (y), and you know it on another point, then you can tell all the points because there's exactly one straight line between 2 points. well we have 2 points. 0, 0 is the left side. the right side is (maxX, maxY) where maxX is maximal mouse, and maxY is maximal scroll. so all in all, you should know you can calculate all the points between using formula ax+b=y

Comment: Aaahhh that's genius i was calculating how much it scrolls when mouse is at x point. I did'nt think of the speed. Thanks